# Scheme (Dr. Racket) Return Lists that Contain some atom

Tags: scheme, racket

I am looking to be able to search through a list of lists in Scheme for an atom in some function called, say, **`google`**. If that list contains the atom, I want to return the list. Ex:

```
(google 'dave '((www.sillypage.com this page says dave among other things)
           (www.happypage.com this page does not say the name)
           (www.theone.com but this dave sure says dave)
          ))
```

should return the list:

```
(www.sillypage.com www.theone.com)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is homework; if it's not homework, please let me know!

With that assumption: this question fits well into the standard design recipe for functions on lists, as described in section 10.1 of [How To Design Programs, edition 2e](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._sec~3alist-produce%29). Take a look, and tell us what step of the design recipe you're stuck on!

Comment: I've looked through that site that you linked and I'm still lost. There doesn't seem to be any examples that are similar to the one I'm trying to do.

Comment: @GregPotts If you break down your problem into "find a thing in a list", "get the first thing in a list", and "produce a list", there are plenty of examples of all three.